# Why does capturing a variable make the type of a lambda unique?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

In the following minimal example:

```
int main()
{
    const int foo = 1;
    const auto a = foo == 1 ? [](){return 42;} : [](){return 4;};
    const auto b = foo == 1 ? [foo](){return 42;} : [foo](){return 4;};
}
```

`a` is fine. `b` however is not, because:

```
<source>:5:29: error: incompatible operand types ('(lambda at <source>:5:31)' and '(lambda at <source>:5:53)')

    const auto b = foo == 1 ? [foo](){return 42;} : [foo](){return 4;};
                            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is that the case? And how can the intended `b` be obtained?

Comment: The const-ness of `foo` might be relevant for the underlying problem, but not for the question as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capturing doesn't make the lambda unique; the lambda type is already unique by definition. However, non-capturing lambda's can be converted to function pointers, and that creates a common type in your first example.

You solve your specific example as follows:

```
const auto b = [foo](){ return (foo == 1) ? 42 : 4;};
```

Comment: A decent optimizer will turn this into `const auto b = []() { return 42; }` when it eliminates the constant `foo`..

Comment: I don't think it can remove the capture though :/ (because of ABI I think).

Comment: @Jarod42: At the binary level, there are three parts to the capture: the storage, initializing the captured value, and using it. The first cannot be eliminated anyway because even non-capturing lambda's have `sizeof > 0`. Initialization and use can be eliminated.

Comment: Whereas we might expect `sizeof([](){return 42;}) == 1`, we have `sizeof([foo](){ /*..*/}) >= sizeof (foo)` even with optimized out `foo`. (whereas we might naively expect a size of 1) :-(

Comment: @Jarod42: That might be the quantum rule of optimizers: looking at the result can change it.

Answer (score 3):

Type of lambda is unique even if it does not capture anything. The way you compare them is not correct, you should compare them directly:

```
auto first{[](){return 42;}};
auto second{[](){return 42;}};
static_assert(not ::std::is_same_v<decltype(first), decltype(second)>);
```

avoiding possible implicit conversion to pointer to function that happens when automatic deduction of type of variable is performed:

```
auto a = foo == 1 ? [](){return 42;} : [](){return 4;};
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int ( * ) (void) , decltype(a)>);
```